# Anchor image from top in CSS when resizing window

Tags: html, css, electron

Is there a way to anchor an image from the top when you resize a window?

[Take a look at this Imgur post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLKSw.jpg). When I resize the window, it anchors from the center, which zooms in the image to the center. That is cool, but the end goal here is to have it zoom in from the top. I want to be able to see the "Luna Li" and "Opal Angel" text even if the screen is wide.

I want the end goal to look like this screenshot, where you can still see the text even if the window isn't a square (this concept was made by changing `top: 30%;`, but this causes the issue of making the background look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vDGm.jpg) in a small window).[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is `object-position`:

```
object-position: 0 0;
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work but I looked it up and it's the right concept. I'll see what I can do, thank you!

Comment: @kyleawayan This is to be applied on the image itself, not on the containing div or similar, if there was any confusion. Let us know what works for you!

Comment: I tried adding it to the image in the chrome developer tools, it still doesn't work :( It's probably due to the other CSS. Here's the CSS that I'm trying to tweak, the picture is under `bg` and `bg img`: https://github.com/Gabe-H/Gemini/blob/fix-background/style.css

Comment: @kyleawayan Please include the relevant HTML and CSS in your question.

Comment: [HTML](https://github.com/Gabe-H/Gemini/blob/fix-background/index.html) [CSS](https://github.com/Gabe-H/Gemini/blob/fix-background/style.css)